# How to load current user emberjs

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data, ember.select

I want to access the current user's information on an account page so it can be edited. I wasn't sure how to fetch the current user, so I set up a route on my server called session.

Accessing '/session' on my server returns a JSON blob, `{ session: {id: "<guid>"}}`, which is the id of the current user in session.

In my `ApplicationRoute`, I fetch the id, fetch the corresponding user model, and then set the model as the `currentUser` property on my `ApplicationController`.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/session', function (data) {
            if (data && data.session && data.session.id) {
                self.set('controller.currentUser', self.store.find('user', data.session.id));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm able to access string properties belonging to the `currentUser` from inside the index template after setting up the `IndexController` like so:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    currentUser: function () {
        return this.get('controllers.application.currentUser');
    }.property('controllers.application.currentUser')
});
```

That's great, but when I try to set up a multiple value [Ember.Select](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html), I get this error:

`Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('roles', []) to the 'content' property of object proxy <DS.PromiseObject:ember435>: its 'content' is undefined.`

I made a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/roket/3/edit?html,js,output)

It demonstrates what I'm trying to do. I'm very confident my error is related to the ajax request, `getJSON`, because my jsbin example works with localstorage.

How should I be loading the current user? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `self.store.find('user', data.session.id)` returns a promise not a record

If you change the code so that you set the `currentUser` to the record that the promise resolves with (like below) then it works correctly.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/session', function (data) {
            if (data && data.session && data.session.id) {
                self.store.find('user', data.session.id).then(function(user){
                    // set this in the "then"
                    self.set('controller.currentUser', user);

                    // you should also be able to change the above line to
                    // controller.set('currentUser', user);
                    // because the "controller" is passed in
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Non working bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xufec/1/edit?js,console,output
Working bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xufec/2/edit?js,console,output

*notice the change in the `ApplicationRoute` from*

```
self.set('controller.currentUser', self.store.find('user', 1));
```

*to*

```
self.store.find('user', 1).then(function(user){
  self.set('controller.currentUser', user);
});
```

---

as a side note you should be able to set the current user using

```
controller.set('currentUser', user);
```

because the controller is passed in

Comment: That seemed to do the trick for me. I started teaching myself about Promises later this evening and figured that was my error. You confirmed it. And thanks for the code cleanup tips.